# Need an idea about how to solve this algorithm puzzle

Tags: c++

So, it is an C++ assignment question and I have been trying since a long time but couldn't get the idea right. This is the question:

> Given two arrays of integers which have the same length, A [0..n-1]
>   and B [0..n-1]. It is necessary to find the first pair of indices i0
>   and j0, i0 <= j0, such that A [i0] + B [j0] = max A [i] + B [j], where
>   0 <= i < n, 0 <= j < n, i <= j.

```
int maxSum(int arrx[], int arry[], int x){
    int i=0, j=0;
    int a;

    while(i <= j && j < x){
        a = arrx[i] + arry[j];
        if(a > arrx[i]){
            cout << i << " " << j << " ";
            i = x;
        }else{
            j++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample of what should be the I/O:
Input:

4

4 -8 6 0

-10 3 1 1

Output:

0 1

Comment: And what exactly is your **question**?

Comment: @DYZ It is what is the way to solve such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your question then, this should work. The answer is 7 that is given from your input data:

```
    int maxSum(int[] arrx, int[] arry, int n)  // n is the size (count) of the array
    {
        int i;
        int j;
        int a;
        int maxVal;
        int saveI;
        int saveJ;

        // first, set maxVal to minimum to make sure you get max val (0 is not necessarily     min value)
        maxVal = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= (n - 1); i++)
        {
            if (arrx[i] < maxVal)
                maxVal = arrx[i];
            if (arrx[j] < maxVal)
                maxVal = arrx[j];
        }

        // now, crawl through the arrays
        for (j = 0; j <= (n - 1); j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i <= j; i++)
            {
                a = arrx[i] + arry[j];

                if (a > maxVal)
                {
                    maxVal = a;
                    saveI = i;
                    saveJ = j;
                    cout << i << " " << j << " " << a " ";
                }
            }
        }

        return maxVal;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort, appreciated. Worked but had to use my own max value of an array function. But may I know what is the purpose of having `saveI` and `saveJ`?

Comment: Just incase you wanted to pass them out or access them after the loops have ended.